# Fill multiple values php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an mysqli table like this:-

```
 id | amount |filled | left
   1| 5.5    |0      | 5.5
   2| 6.7    |0      | 6.7
   3| 4.1    |3.1    | 1
```

I have an php variable like this:-

```
 $ar = array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 =>3);
```

So how do I make an sql query which would make all the ids filled same as amount and left to 0 .

So that table becomes like:-

```
   id | amount |filled | left
     1| 5.5    |5.5    | 0
     2| 6.7    |6.7    | 0
     3| 4.1    |4.1    | 0
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: But this not see easy for me as amounts are different and i need to finish in one query

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see what you mean by 'all the ids filled same as amount and left to 0'. Please show us the output you are looking for. And also what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions
SET filled = amount, left = 0;
```

I have no idea what your PHP array variable has to do with this task.